# Execute string result from shell script as a set of shell commands

Tags: shell, shell-script, command

I create a string result from my `shell script` and i want to execute it as a `shell command`.

For example `file_a` is:

```
user1@gmail.com
user2@gmail.com
```

script:

```
awk '{print "mail -s \"welcome\"", $1}' file_a
```

And result:

```
mail -s "welcome" user1@gmail.com
mail -s "welcome" user2@gmail.com
```

So i want to execute the result as a set of shell commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look into the eval command.

```
eval $(awk '{print "mail -s \"welcome\"", $1}' file_a)
```

---

**EDIT:** 
You're right @manatwork--eval as I demonstrated wouldn't really work for multiple lines. I was trying to answer Navid's question as he asked it, but really I shouldn't have been afraid to ask him why he wasn't just using a for loop, i.e.:

```
for m in $(<file_a); do mail -s welcome $m
```

Comment: Are you sure? For me this works only for single line output, not with multiple lines as in the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ways:

- write the output of awk to a file, make the file executable, and then execute it
- use the system() function in the awk script:

Answer (score 2):

Directly reading and executing command in bash.

```
for i in `<file_a`; do mail -s "welcome" $i; done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can play with xargs.

> xargs - build and execute command lines from standard input

And a example couple be like this

```
awk '{print "mail -s \"welcome\"", $1}' file_a | xargs -0 bash -c
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe the result of `àwk` to `bash`:

```
awk '{print "mail -s \"welcome\"", $1}' file_a | bash
```

But be careful on the output of the 1st command, as if `file_a` contains some tricky lines, you could execute unwanted commands.